# Limit of probability that sum of $n$ iid variables is greater than $0$

Tags: probability, limits, central-limit-theorem, probability-limit-theorems

How can I find the probability $$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i>0\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i>0\right)$$ if $X_i$ are iid? If the expectation of $X_i$ is less than $0$, then by the law of large numbers, the limit probability would be $0$. Conversely, if the expectation is greater than $0$, the limit probability would be $1$. What I'm having trouble with is if the expectation is exactly $0$.

If the distribution is symmetric about $x=0$, then the probability is $\frac{1}{2}$ by symmetry. I think it may actually always be $\frac{1}{2}$ since the average of $n$ iid variables would approximately be the normal distribution $N\left(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$ by the central limit theorem where $\sigma^2$ is the variance of $X_i$.

Is it true that the limit probability would be $\frac{1}{2}$ no matter what the exact distribution is (assuming the mean is $0$)? To me, this seems somewhat counterintuitive, but it is the only result I get.

Comment: In math, theorems trump intuition.  If a theorem implies a thing that you find counterintuitive, it is you who has to adjust, not the thing.

Comment: @JakeMirra Yes that is true, but what if the theorem is applied incorrectly? I don't know if I applied the central limit theorem correctly in this case.

Comment: Indeed, the limit is $\frac12$ as long as the central limit theorem applies (namely, as long as the distribution has finite variance).

Comment: @MikeEarnest What about if the variance is not finite? Would the probability just not be defined in that case, or something more complex?

Comment: @VarunVejalla Hmm, I have not thought about it and am not sure.